# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType' Trying to take in a float from user

Tags: python

So essentially I'm trying to make a combustion analysis solver where it takes in a mass (with the likelihood of there being decimals) of water and carbon dioxide (CO2) and then also the mass of the  CxHyOz to find the empirical formula for such a problem. But it is giving me an error on my input line. It's been many years since I've written in python but I figured it would be faster this way because of the minimal syntax required lol. one small project has now taken up many hours.

The error I'm getting...

```
>>> 
= RESTART: C:/Users/Minec/OneDrive/Documents/Python Files/CombustionAnalysis.py
What is the mass of the CO2? 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Minec/OneDrive/Documents/Python Files/CombustionAnalysis.py", line 9, in <module>
    massCarbonDioxide = float(print("What is the mass of the CO2? "))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
>>>
```

my code:

```
##Constants
waterMM = 18.0158
carbonDioxideMM = 44.0115
cMM = 12.010
hMM = 1.0078
oMM = 15.999

##variable inputs
massCarbonDioxide = float(print("What is the mass of the CO2? "))
massWater = float(print("What is the mass of the water? "))
totMass = float(print("What is the total mass of the compound X? "))

#calculating moles of CO2 and water
molesCarbonDioxide = massCarbonDioxide / carbonDioxdideMM
molesWater = massWater / waterMM

#calculating moles of Hydrogen and Carbon
molesH = 2 * molesWater
molesC = molesCarbonDioxide

#calulating mass of Hydrogen Carbon and Oxygen
massH = molesH * hMM
massC = molesC * cMM
massO = (totMass - massC) - massH

#dealing with oxygen
oxygenPresent = false
molesO = 0.0000000000000000000
if(massO > 0):
    molesO = massO / oMM
    oxygenPresent = true

#finding the minimum moles
minMole = 0.000000000000000000
if(oxygenPresent):
    if(molesH < molesC):
        if(molesH < molesO):
            minMole = molesH
        else:
            minMole = molesO
    else:
        if(molesC < molesO):
            minMoles = molesC
        else:
            minMoles = molesO
else:
    if(molesH < molesC):
        minMoles = molesH
    else:
        minMoles = molesC

#calculating mole ratio
molesH = molesH / minMoles
molesC = molesC / minMoles
if(oxygenPresent):
    molesO = molesO / minMoles

i = 1
if(oxygenPresent):
    if(molesH == 1):
        go = true
        while(go):
            if((((molesC * i) % 1) > 85) or (((molesC * i) % 1) < 15)):
                molesC = molesC * i
                molesO = molesO * i
                molesC = round(molesC,0)
                molesH = molesH * i
                if((((molesO * 1) % 1) > 85) or (((molesO * 1) % 1) < 15)):
                    molesO = round(molesO,0)
                else:
                    gogo = true
                    ii = 1
                    while(gogo):
                        if((((molesO * ii) % 1) > 85) or (((molesO * ii) % 1) < 15)):
                            molesO = molesO * ii
                            molesO = round(molesO,0)
                            molesH = molesH * ii
                            molesC = molesC * ii
                            gogo = false
                        else:
                            ii = ii + 1
                go = false
            else:
                i = i + 1
    elif(molesC == 1):
        go = true
        while(go):
            if((((molesH * i) % 1) > 85) or (((molesH * i) % 1) < 15)):
                molesH = molesH * i
                molesO = molesO * i
                molesH = round(molesH,0)
                molesC = molesC * i
                if((((molesO * 1) % 1) > 85) or (((molesO * 1) % 1) < 15)):
                    molesO = round(molesO,0)
                else:
                    gogo = true
                    ii = 1
                    while(gogo):
                        if((((molesO * ii) % 1) > 85) or (((molesO * ii) % 1) < 15)):
                            molesO = molesO * ii
                            molesO = round(molesO,0)
                            molesH = molesH * ii
                            molesC = molesC * ii
                            gogo = false
                        else:
                            ii = ii + 1
                go = false
            else:
                i = i + 1
    else:
        go = true
        while(go):
            if((((molesC * i) % 1) > 85) or (((molesC * i) % 1) < 15)):
                molesC = molesC * i
                molesH = molesH * i
                molesC = round(molesC,0)
                molesO = molesO * i
                if((((molesH * 1) % 1) > 85) or (((molesH * 1) % 1) < 15)):
                    molesH = round(molesH,0)
                else:
                    gogo = true
                    ii = 1
                    while(gogo):
                        if((((molesH * ii) % 1) > 85) or (((molesH * ii) % 1) < 15)):
                            molesH = molesH * ii
                            molesH = round(molesH,0)
                            molesO = molesO * ii
                            molesC = molesC * ii
                            gogo = false
                        else:
                            ii = ii + 1
                go = false
            else:
                i = i + 1
else:
    if(molesH == 1):
        go = true
        while(go):
            if((((molesC * i) % 1) > 85) or (((molesC * i) % 1) < 15)):
                molesC = molesC * i
                molesC = round(molesC,0)
                molesH = molesH * i
                go = false
            else:
                i = i + 1
    else:
        go = true
        while(go):
            if((((molesH * i) % 1) > 85) or (((molesH * i) % 1) < 15)):
                molesH = molesH * i
                molesH = round(molesH,0)
                molesC = molesC * i
                go = false
            else:
                i = i + 1


#printing out the empirical formula
if(oxygenPresent):
    print("C",molesC,"H",molesH,"O",molesO)
else:
    print("C",molesC,"H",molesH)
```

Edit: Thanks for all the help! Here is the final-ish version for anyone who is interested...

```
##Author  - Zach Wilson
##Date    - 9.26.21
##Purpose - to teach and solve combustion analysis problems for chemistry
##Version - 1.0
##Notes   - I have not done any optimizations to the code as it was the first pass and easier just to do everything the long way...
##            prolly won't update this program only fix any errors in my math should they arise


##Constants
explanations = bool(False)
waterMM = 18.0158
carbonDioxideMM = 44.0115
cMM = 12.010
hMM = 1.0078
oMM = 15.999


#introduction
print("This program was made by Zach Wilson to help learn/teach how to solve for CxHyOz.")
print("This is typically called a cumbustion analysis problem.")
question = str(input("Do you want to see the explanations (yes/no)? "))
if(question == "yes"or"Yes"or"YES"or"yEs"or"yeS"or"YEs"or"yES"or"y"or"Y"or"ye"or"Ye"or"yE"or"YE"):
    explanations = = bool(True)
print("\n")


##variable inputs
massCarbonDioxide = float(input("What is the mass of the CO2? "))
massWater = float(input("What is the mass of the water? "))
totMass = float(input("What is the total mass of the compound X? "))
molecMM = float(input("What is the molecular molar mass? "))
print("    \n")

#calculating moles of CO2 and water
molesCarbonDioxide = massCarbonDioxide / carbonDioxideMM  
molesWater = massWater / waterMM
##printing the calculation
if(explanations):
    print("We first need to convert our masses into the mol of H2O and CO2, respectively...")
string = str(massCarbonDioxide)+"g CO2    "
emptystring = ""
for i in range(0, len(string)):
    emptystring = emptystring + string[i]+str('\u0332')
if(explanations):
    print("mol CO2  =  ", emptystring, "   =  ", round(molesCarbonDioxide, 5),"mol CO2")
    print("            ", carbonDioxideMM,"g/mol CO2")
    print("    ")
string = str(massWater)+"g CO2    "
emptystring = ""
for i in range(0, len(string)):
    emptystring = emptystring + string[i]+str('\u0332')
if(explanations):
    print("mol H2O(water)  =  ", emptystring, "      =  ", round(molesWater, 5),"mol H2O(water)")
    print("                  ", waterMM,"g/mol H2O")
    print("    \n")


#calculating moles of Hydrogen and Carbon
molesH = 2 * molesWater
molesC = molesCarbonDioxide

if(explanations):
    print("Then to find the moles of hyrdogen and carbon,\n   we multiply the amount of hydrogen in H2O (2) by the mol of water that we previously calculated.")
    print("We then do the same for carbon respectively...")
    print("moles of Hydrogen (in H2O) = 2 *", round(molesWater, 5),"mol H2O =  ", molesH,"mol H")
    print("moles of Carbon (in CO2) = 1 *", round(molesCarbonDioxide, 5),"mol CO2 =  ", molesC,"mol C")
    print("    \n")

#calulating mass of Hydrogen Carbon and Oxygen
massH = molesH * hMM
massC = molesC * cMM
massO = (totMass - massC) - massH

if(explanations):
    print("After we have the moles of H from the water vapor produced,\n   we then multiply it by the molar mass of hydrogen and the same steps for carbon...")
    print("mass of Hydrogen = ",round(molesH, 5)," *", hMM, " =  ", round(massH, 5),"g H")
    print("mass of Carbon =  ",round(molesC, 5)," *", cMM, " =  ", round(massC, 5),"g C")
    print("    \n")
    print("Then we must determine whether or not there is any Oxygen in the original compound.")
    print("To do so, we take the total mass of the original compound,\n   then subtract that by the mass of Hydrogen and Carbon that we just clalculated...")
    print("mass of Oxygen =  ",totMass,"g Compound-X"," -", round(massC, 5),"g C"," -", round(massH, 5),"g H",  " =  ", round(massO, 5),"g O")
    if(massO > 0):
        print("    \n")
    else:
        print("      In this case, there is no oxygen so we will be ignoring it from now on. \n \n")


#dealing with oxygen
oxygenPresent = bool(False)
molesO = 0.0000000000000000000
if(massO > 0):
    if(explanations):
        print("Now since we have oxygen, we need to calcualate the moles of oxygen we have...")
    molesO = massO / oMM
    if(explanations):
        print("moles of O  = ", round(massO, 5),"g O  / ", oMM,"g/mol  = ", round(molesO, 5),"mol O")
    oxygenPresent = bool(True)
    if(explanations):
        print("    \n")


#finding the minimum moles
if(explanations):
    print("Now we need to calulate the mole ratio.")
    print("To do so we must divide each of the moles that we calculated by,\n   dividing by the smallest amount so that we can start with 1 and multipy to whole numbers from there")
    print("In this case the smallest amount is...")
minMole = 0.000000000000000000
minMoleElem = ""
if(oxygenPresent):
    if(molesH < molesC):
        if(molesH < molesO):
            minMole = molesH
            if(explanations):
                print("Hydrogen with ", molesH," moles")
            minMoleElem = minMoleElem + "H" 
        else:
            minMole = molesO
            if(explanations):
                print("Oxygen with ", molesO," moles")
            minMoleElem = minMoleElem + "O"
    else:
        if(molesC < molesO):
            minMoles = molesC
            if(explanations):
                print("Carbon with ", molesC," moles")
            minMoleElem = minMoleElem + "C"
        else:
            minMoles = molesO
            if(explanations):
                print("Oxygen with ", molesO," moles")
            minMoleElem = minMoleElem + "O"
else:
    if(molesH < molesC):
        minMoles = molesH
        if(explanations):
            print("Hydrogen with ", molesH," moles")
        minMoleElem = minMoleElem + "H"
    else:
        minMoles = molesC
        if(explanations):
            print("Carbon with ", molesC," moles")
        minMoleElem = minMoleElem + "C"
if(explanations):
    print(" ")

#calculating mole ratio
if(explanations):
    print("mol H  = ", round(molesH, 5),"mol H  / ", minMoles,"mol", minMoleElem, " = ", round((molesH / minMoles), 5),"mol H")
molesH = molesH / minMoles
if(explanations):
    print("mol C  = ", round(molesO, 5),"mol C  / ", minMoles,"mol", minMoleElem, " = ", round((molesC / minMoles), 5),"mol C")
molesC = molesC / minMoles
if(oxygenPresent):
    if(explanations):
        print("mol O  = ", round(molesO, 5),"mol O  / ", minMoles,"mol", minMoleElem, " = ", round((molesO / minMoles), 5),"mol O")
    molesO = molesO / minMoles
if(explanations):
    print("    \n")

#print("     ")
#print("-=-=-=Debugging=-=-=-")
#print(molesH)
#print(molesC)
#print(molesO)
#print("-=-=End of Debugging=-=-")
#print("     ")

#formating spaces
sn = " "
nH = "      "
HC = "         "
CO = "       "


#multiplying up
if(explanations):
    print("Now for the more challenging part, we need to start multiplying upwards to get the nearest whole number for each...")
i = 1
if(oxygenPresent):
    if(explanations):
        print("  n       moles H       moles C       moles O  ")  
    if(molesH == 1):
        go = bool(True)
        while(go):
            if((((molesC * i) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesC * i) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                molesC = molesC * i
                molesO = molesO * i
                molesC = round(molesC,0)
                molesH = molesH * i
                if((((molesO * 1) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesO * 1) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                    molesO = round(molesO,0)
                    if(explanations):
                        print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,CO,molesO,"  ")
                else:
                    gogo = bool(True)
                    ii = 1
                    while(gogo):
                        if((((molesO * ii) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesO * ii) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                            molesO = molesO * ii
                            molesO = round(molesO,0)
                            molesH = molesH * ii
                            molesC = molesC * ii
                            gogo = bool(False)
                            if(explanations):
                                print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,CO,molesO,"  ")
                        else:
                            if(explanations):
                                print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,CO,round(molesO, 2),"  ")
                            ii = ii + 1
                go = bool(False)
            else:
                if(explanations):
                    print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,round(molesC, 2),CO,round(molesO, 2),"  ")
                i = i + 1
    elif(molesC == 1):
        go = bool(True)
        while(go):
            if((((molesH * i) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesH * i) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                molesH = molesH * i
                molesO = molesO * i
                molesH = round(molesH,0)
                molesC = molesC * i
                if((((molesO * 1) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesO * 1) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                    molesO = round(molesO,0)
                    if(explanations):
                        print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,CO,molesO,"  ")
                else:
                    gogo = bool(True)
                    ii = 1
                    while(gogo):
                        if((((molesO * ii) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesO * ii) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                            molesO = molesO * ii
                            molesO = round(molesO,0)
                            molesH = molesH * ii
                            molesC = molesC * ii
                            gogo = bool(False)
                            if(explanations):
                                print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,CO,molesO,"  ")
                        else:
                            if(explanations):
                                print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,CO,round(molesO, 2),"  ")
                            ii = ii + 1
                go = bool(False)
            else:
                if(explanations):
                    print(sn,i,nH,round(molesH, 2),HC,molesC,CO,round(molesO, 2),"  ")
                i = i + 1
    else:
        go = bool(True)
        while(go):
            if((((molesC * i) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesC * i) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                molesC = molesC * i
                molesH = molesH * i
                molesC = round(molesC,0)
                molesO = molesO * i
                if((((molesH * 1) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesH * 1) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                    molesH = round(molesH,0)
                    if(explanations):
                        print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,CO,molesO,"  ")
                else:
                    gogo = bool(True)
                    ii = 1
                    while(gogo):
                        if((((molesH * ii) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesH * ii) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                            molesH = molesH * ii
                            molesH = round(molesH,0)
                            molesO = molesO * ii
                            molesC = molesC * ii
                            gogo = bool(False)
                            if(explanations):
                                print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,CO,molesO,"  ")
                        else:
                            if(explanations):
                                print(sn,i,nH,round(molesH, 2),HC,molesC,CO,molesO,"  ")
                            ii = ii + 1
                go = bool(False)
            else:
                if(explanations):
                    print(sn,i,nH,round(molesH, 2),HC,round(molesC, 2),CO,molesO,"  ")
                i = i + 1
else:
    if(explanations):
        print("  n       moles H       moles C  ")
    if(molesH == 1):
        go = bool(True)
        while(go):
            if((((molesC * i) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesC * i) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                #print("-=-=-=Debugging=-=-=-")
                #print(((molesC * i) % 1) * 10, "  ", molesH * i)
                #print("-=-=End of Debugging=-=-")
                molesC = molesC * i
                molesC = round(molesC,0)
                molesH = molesH * i
                go = bool(False)
                if(explanations):
                    print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,"  ")
            else:
                #print("-=-=-=Debugging=-=-=-")
                #print(molesC * i, "  ", molesH * i)
                #print("-=-=End of Debugging=-=-")
                if(explanations):
                    print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,round(molesC, 2),"  ")
                i = i + 1
    else:
        go = bool(True)
        while(go):
            if((((molesH * i) % 1) * 100 > 85) or (((molesH * i) % 1) * 100 < 15)):
                molesH = molesH * i
                molesH = round(molesH,0)
                molesC = molesC * i
                go = bool(False)
                if(explanations):
                    print(sn,i,nH,molesH,HC,molesC,"  ")
            else:
                if(explanations):
                    print(sn,i,nH,round(molesH, 2),HC,molesC,"  ")
                i = i + 1
if(explanations):
    print("\n And there we have our table of whole numbers, which will now plug in as our imperical formula...")
    print("    \n")


#printing out the empirical formula
molesCint = int(molesC)
molesHint = int(molesH)
molesOint = int(molesO)
print("     ")
print("The imperical formula")
if(oxygenPresent):
    print("C",molesCint,"H",molesHint,"O",molesOint)
else:
    print("C",molesCint,"H",molesHint)
print("     \n")

##calculating the adjustment for the molecular formula
if(explanations):
    print("Now we need to adjust for the melecular formula,")
    print("To do so, we take the molar mass of our empirical formula...")
if(oxygenPresent):
    molarMassOfPrev = (molesC * cMM) + (molesH * hMM) + (molesO * oMM)
    if(explanations):
        print(" moles of C",molesCint,"H",molesHint,"O",molesOint, " = (",molesC,"mol C * ",cMM,"g/mol C) + (",molesH,"mol H * ",hMM,"g/mol H) + (",molesO,"mol O * ",oMM,"g/mol O) = ",molarMassOfPrev,"mol C",molesCint,"H",molesHint,"O",molesOint)      
else:
    molarMassOfPrev = (molesC * cMM) + (molesH * hMM)
    if(explanations):
        print(" moles of C",molesCint,"H",molesHint, " = (",molesC,"mol C * ",cMM,"g/mol) + (",molesH,"mol H * ",hMM,"g/mol H) = ",molarMassOfPrev,"mol C",molesCint,"H",molesHint)
molecAdjust = molecMM / molarMassOfPrev
if(explanations):
    print("\n","We then take the molecular mass given to us and divid it by what we just calculated from the impirical formula.")
    print("adjustment = ", molecMM,"g/mol  /  ", molarMassOfPrev,"g/mol  = ", round(molecAdjust, 5),"... ~",int(round(molecAdjust, 0)))
    print("Then just multiply the adjustment to each element in the compound-X.")

#print("     ")
#print("-=-=-=Debugging=-=-=-")
#print(molecAdjust)
#print(molecMM)
#print(molarMassOfPrev)
#print("-=-=End of Debugging=-=-")
#print("     ")


molecAdjust = round(molecAdjust, 0)
molesC = molesC * molecAdjust
molesH = molesH * molecAdjust
molesO = molesO * molecAdjust
molesCint = int(molesC)
molesHint = int(molesH)
molesOint = int(molesO)

#print("     ")
#print("-=-=-=Debugging=-=-=-")
#print(molecAdjust)
#print("-=-=End of Debugging=-=-")
#print("     ")


#printing out the molecular formula
print("     \n")
print("The molecular formula")
if(oxygenPresent):
    print("C",molesCint,"H",molesHint,"O",molesOint)
else:
    print("C",molesCint,"H",molesHint)
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `float(input('text'))` instead of `float(print('text'))`?

Answer (score 1):

I am very dumb the input lines under secition ##variable inputs
needed to read:

```
##variable inputs
massCarbonDioxide = float(input("What is the mass of the CO2? "))
massWater = float(input("What is the mass of the water? "))
totMass = float(input("What is the total mass of the compound X? "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Python `print` function does not return anything. Instead, it simply outputs to the console. That is why Python is complaining about trying to convert a none type to a float.

You need an input, however, and that can be done with the `input` function like so:

```
massCarbonDioxide = float(input("What is the mass of the CO2? "))
```

Just to note, your booleans also should be capitalized. Rather than `false`, it should be `False`!

Comment: Thank you. will do. it truly was just the first pass and i was just tryin to get it running.